# Automatic word generator

Tags: ios, xcode, random, generator

(I'm working in Xcode for iOS)

I'm making a word game and when I click Game from the menu it switches to the game view. I want it to automatic display a random word that I inserted. I read I had to put my code in the ViewDidLoad and I did.

However the code was original for the use of a Button then display a random word so I don't know how to edit the code.

here it is:

```
.h

IBOutlet UILabel *textview;

}

-(IBAction)random;
```

and the .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

-(IBAction)random { 
    int text = rand() % 5;
    switch (text) {
        case 0:
            textview.text = @"BLUE";
            break;
        case 1:
            textview.text = @"GREEN";
            break;
        case 2:
            textview.text = @"RED";
            break;
        case 3:
            textview.text = @"YELLOW";
            break;
        case 4:
            textview.text = @"PINK";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me out thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that everything is part of a view controller, just call your random() method from your viewDidLoad.

Comment: wooh nicenthanks so much :) really getting this game alive :D

Answer (score 0):

Just switch your code from the IBAction to your viewDidLoad - make sure (if you're using IB or storyboarding) that you have a UILabel linked to your code (make sure you synthesize it in the .m) -

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
```

...then in viewDidLoad -

```
self.myLabel.text = whateverText;
```

(You don't have to have it as a property, but it makes the memory management stuff easier)

Also, probably not a good idea to use the name "textview" for a UILabel, as you could easily think it was a UITextView, which is a different animal...